# Testing Pubnub + WebRTC Scalability

Tags: testing, scalability, one-to-many, webrtc, pubnub

Finally got a working set up that I am happy with for now using Pubnub + WebRTC.
I want to now test how well this would all scale but really do not know where to start, test broadcasting one to many.

I want to be able to test 100 different connections (viewers receiving the stream) then later move up to 1000 if this is successful.

Would appreciate any suggestions from those more experience out there :]

Comment: Testing is always challenging and you will likely run into client-limitations which create false results.  Do you need to test the Video streams as well?